# jQuery append a href string cant click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day to all programmers over there but I have some problems which the html code from javascript doesn't work. I append this code but can't click after showing on the html `<div id="result"></div>`

```
$('#result').append('<div class="col-large-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 float-left"><div class="col-md-12 column thumbnailbox"><img src="img/IMAGE.png" style="position: absolute; width: 32px; height: 32px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;" ></img><img src="https://instagram.fmnl4-6.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c135.0.810.810/22636828_1183035351797075_5642980100820434944_n.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></img><div class="thumbnailtitle"><button href="#" class="btn-download btn btn-block btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">DOWNLOAD IMAGE</button></div></div></div>';
```

It appends but can't click the link on href

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Look for **event delegation** as you elements are dynamic so any previously attached event listeners won't work on them unless they're (the event listeners) in delegation mode.

Comment: I found a little bit of a solution by removing the pull-left it will finally worked but the problem is the design, removing the pull-left will destroy everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this in the append: it opens a new tab with the image, someone can save it.

Notice I have changed button into anchor

```html
<div class="col-large-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 float-left"><div class="col-md-12 column thumbnailbox"><img src="img/IMAGE.png" style="position: absolute; width: 32px; height: 32px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;" ></img><img src="https://instagram.fmnl4-6.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c135.0.810.810/22636828_1183035351797075_5642980100820434944_n.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></img><div class="thumbnailtitle"><a href="https://instagram.fmnl4-6.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c135.0.810.810/22636828_1183035351797075_5642980100820434944_n.jpg" class="btn-download btn btn-block btn-danger btn-sm" role="button" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD IMAGE</a></div></div></div>
```

Or you may need to open a link to a page that forces download.

Answer (score 2):

`button` elements don't have `href` attributes.  You need to use an `a` element.  You can style it like a button:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: still unable to click sir

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/6z3zLz12/), seems to be clickable.